# InvalidCastException on an LDAP implementation in ASP Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-boilerplate

Good day all, recently had to implement an Active Directory for our application and we have come across an InvalidCastException when trying to log into the site for the past few days I have been at our wits end trying to figure out what is causing this error. The code does seems to run fine as there are no errors when loading

LdapAuthentication.cs:

```
 public abstract class LdapAuthenticationSource<TTenant, TUser> : DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<TTenant, TUser>, ITransientDependency
        where TTenant : AbpTenant<TUser>
        where TUser : AbpUserBase, new()
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// LDAP
        /// </summary>
        public const string SourceName = "LDAP";

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return SourceName; }
        }

        private readonly ILdapSettings _settings;
        private readonly IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig _ldapModuleConfig;

        protected LdapAuthenticationSource(ILdapSettings settings, IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig ldapModuleConfig)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _ldapModuleConfig = ldapModuleConfig;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public override async Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, TTenant tenant)
        {
            if (!_ldapModuleConfig.IsEnabled || !(await _settings.GetIsEnabled(GetIdOrNull(tenant))))
            {
                return false;
            }

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                return ValidateCredentials(principalContext, userNameOrEmailAddress, plainPassword);
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public async override Task<TUser> CreateUserAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, TTenant tenant)
        {
            await CheckIsEnabled(tenant);

            var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(userNameOrEmailAddress, tenant);

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userNameOrEmailAddress);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    throw new AbpException("Unknown LDAP user: " + userNameOrEmailAddress);
                }

                UpdateUserFromPrincipal(user, userPrincipal);

                user.IsEmailConfirmed = true;
                user.IsActive = true;

                return user;
            }
        }

        public async override Task UpdateUserAsync(TUser user, TTenant tenant)
        {
            await CheckIsEnabled(tenant);

            await base.UpdateUserAsync(user, tenant);

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user.UserName);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    throw new AbpException("Unknown LDAP user: " + user.UserName);
                }

                UpdateUserFromPrincipal(user, userPrincipal);
            }
        }

        protected virtual bool ValidateCredentials(PrincipalContext principalContext, string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword)
        {
            return principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userNameOrEmailAddress, plainPassword, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
        }

        protected virtual void UpdateUserFromPrincipal(TUser user, UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
        {
            user.UserName = userPrincipal.SamAccountName;
            user.Name = userPrincipal.GivenName;
            user.Surname = userPrincipal.Surname;
            user.EmailAddress = userPrincipal.EmailAddress;

            if (userPrincipal.Enabled.HasValue)
            {
                user.IsActive = userPrincipal.Enabled.Value;
            }
        }

        protected virtual async Task<PrincipalContext> CreatePrincipalContext(TTenant tenant)
        {
            var tenantId = GetIdOrNull(tenant);

            return new PrincipalContext(
                await _settings.GetContextType(tenantId),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetDomain(tenantId)),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetContainer(tenantId)),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetUserName(tenantId)),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetPassword(tenantId))
                );
        }

        private async Task CheckIsEnabled(TTenant tenant)
        {
            if (!_ldapModuleConfig.IsEnabled)
            {
                throw new AbpException("Ldap Authentication module is disabled globally!");
            }

            var tenantId = GetIdOrNull(tenant);
            if (!await _settings.GetIsEnabled(tenantId))
            {
                throw new AbpException("Ldap Authentication is disabled for given tenant (id:" + tenantId + ")! You can enable it by setting '" + LdapSettingNames.IsEnabled + "' to true");
            }
        }

        private static int? GetIdOrNull(TTenant tenant)
        {
            return tenant == null
                ? (int?)null
                : tenant.Id;
        }

        private static string ConvertToNullIfEmpty(string str)
        {
            return str.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
                ? null
                : str;
        }

    }
}
```

LdapSettings.cs

```
public class LdapSettings: ILdapSettings, ITransientDependency
    {

        protected ISettingManager SettingManager { get; }

        public LdapSettings(ISettingManager settingManager)
        {
            SettingManager = settingManager;
        }

        public virtual Task<bool> GetIsEnabled(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync<bool>(AppSettingNames.IsEnabled, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync<bool>(AppSettingNames.IsEnabled);
        }

        public virtual async Task<ContextType> GetContextType(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? (await SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.ContextType, tenantId.Value)).ToEnum<ContextType>()
                : (await SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.ContextType)).ToEnum<ContextType>();
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetContainer(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.Container, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.Container);
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetDomain(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.Domain, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.Domain);
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetUserName(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.UserName, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.UserName);
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetPassword(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.Password, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

CoreModule.cs

```
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroLdapModule))]
    public class TestApp2020CoreModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {

            Configuration.Auditing.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;

            // Declare entity types
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Tenant = typeof(Tenant);
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Role = typeof(Role);
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.User = typeof(User);

            TestApp2020LocalizationConfigurer.Configure(Configuration.Localization);

            // Enable this line to create a multi-tenant application.
            Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = TestApp2020Consts.MultiTenancyEnabled;

            // IocManager.Register<ILdapSettings, MyLdapSettings>(); //change default setting source
            IocManager.Register<ILdapSettings, LdapSettings>();
            Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof(LdapSettings));
            // Configure roles
            AppRoleConfig.Configure(Configuration.Modules.Zero().RoleManagement);

            Configuration.Settings.Providers.Add<AppSettingProvider>();
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(TestApp2020CoreModule).GetAssembly());
        }

        public override void PostInitialize()
        {
            IocManager.Resolve<AppTimes>().StartupTime = Clock.Now;
            SettingManager settingsManager = IocManager.Resolve<SettingManager>();
            settingsManager.ChangeSettingForApplication(AppSettingNames.IsEnabled, "true");
        }
    }
}
```

The application loads but the an error here prevents logging in
[image]

And this is what is showing in the logs
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi, I can read the text that you've obscured in the stack trace. If you don't want others to read it I suggest you reupload a version in which you've placed a solid square of colour over it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr;

Your problem is in `CoreModule.cs`

```
Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof(LdapSettings));
```

According to [the docs](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/M_Abp_Zero_Ldap_Configuration_IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig_Enable.htm) the `Enable` method takes an auth source type as a parameter, but you've passed a settings type.  Change it to use `LdapAuthenticationSource` instead.

## How you could have figured this out

The error message says there was a failed cast from `LdapSettings` to `IExternalAuthenticationSource`.  That's strange because there's no reason your code should be trying to cast between those types!

If you look down the stack, you can see the error is happening inside your `TokenAuthController`'s `Authenticate` / `GetLoginResultAsync` method.  You could check the code in that method, you probably won't find any direct mention of either `LdapSettings` or `IExternalAuthenticationSource`.  You will however find a call to `ApbLoginManger.LoginAsync`.  Follow that back up the stack and you can see `ApbLoginManager` uses IoC to resolve an auth source, and the exception is thrown in the `ResolveAsDisposable` method of IoC!

It gets a bit trickier here.  The bug is *presenting* itself deep inside ABP and the IoC framework.  It's possible there's an obscure bug in one of those frameworks causing the problem, but it's much more likely to be a *configuration error*.  That means the next step is to look through your configuration code for anywhere you may have told the IoC framework to use `LdapSettings` for an `IExternalAuthenticationSource`.

All the config happens in the `CoreModule.cs` file, so let's look there.  You have a call to

```
IocManager.Register<ILdapSettings, LdapSettings>();
```

which seems to properly register `LdapSettings` for `ILdapSettings`.  The only other call to `IocManager` is the standard call to `IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention` in the `Initialize` method.  No obvious misconfiguration there.  There is however a call that uses `typeof(LdapSettings)` as a parameter.

```
Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof(LdapSettings));
```

It's not obvious from the method call what that parameter is for, and `LdapSettings` is definitely a reasonable possibility for the correct parameter.  However, there are two good reasons to look into this method further.

1. Because the parameter is a `Type`, there won't be compile time checking if we've passed an appropriate type.
2. `LdapSettings` is part of the actual exception so any method that uses it is suspect

That brings us to [the documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/M_Abp_Zero_Ldap_Configuration_IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig_Enable.htm) where we see the problem.  We need to pass the auth source, not the settings.

## Why the code "seems to run fine"

The configuration used a `Type` parameter instead of generics.  That means there's no compile time checking if you've passed a valid type (as mentioned above).  The program compile and run fine *until you try to use the misconfigured code*.  In this case, the misconifguration won't be used until you try to login, which triggers the IoC resolver, which accesses the config, and throws the error.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks! That did help somewhat but there's different error showing up in the logs saying No Component Found for LdapAuthenticationSource, still investigating.

Comment: @Raze711 Without seeing the code, I would assume it's a problem with generic types.  Did you use `typeof(LdapAuthenticationSource<,>)` as your parameter?  Or something that specified the values of those generic params like `typeof(LdapAuthenticationSource<AbpTenant<User>, AbpUserBase>)`?

Comment: Certainly, used  Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof(LdapAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>)); in the CoreModule

Comment: @Raze711 that looks like you've got the typeof correct.  There's probably another config error unrelated to the first one.  It might have to do with your constructor.  You're not calling the base constructor like the docs tell you to (see "LDAP/Active Directory" on [this page](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management)).  If you have further questions on that point, please open a new SO question.

Comment: Just opened another question on this, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191897/mvc-exceptionhandling-abpexceptionfilter-no-component-found