# Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - No Component found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-boilerplate

this is a follow-up question to the one posted here earlier today [InvalidCastException on an LDAP implementation in ASP Boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189660/invalidcastexception-on-an-ldap-implementation-in-asp-boilerplate) as suggested by just.another.programmer

I seem to be running into another issue this time having no component supported as described here in the logs

[image]

The code from before

LdapAuthentication.cs:

```
 public abstract class LdapAuthenticationSource<TTenant, TUser> : DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<TTenant, TUser>, ITransientDependency
        where TTenant : AbpTenant<TUser>
        where TUser : AbpUserBase, new()
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// LDAP
        /// </summary>
        public const string SourceName = "LDAP";

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return SourceName; }
        }

        private readonly ILdapSettings _settings;
        private readonly IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig _ldapModuleConfig;

        protected LdapAuthenticationSource(ILdapSettings settings, IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig ldapModuleConfig)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _ldapModuleConfig = ldapModuleConfig;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public override async Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, TTenant tenant)
        {
            if (!_ldapModuleConfig.IsEnabled || !(await _settings.GetIsEnabled(GetIdOrNull(tenant))))
            {
                return false;
            }

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                return ValidateCredentials(principalContext, userNameOrEmailAddress, plainPassword);
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public async override Task<TUser> CreateUserAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, TTenant tenant)
        {
            await CheckIsEnabled(tenant);

            var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(userNameOrEmailAddress, tenant);

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userNameOrEmailAddress);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    throw new AbpException("Unknown LDAP user: " + userNameOrEmailAddress);
                }

                UpdateUserFromPrincipal(user, userPrincipal);

                user.IsEmailConfirmed = true;
                user.IsActive = true;

                return user;
            }
        }

        public async override Task UpdateUserAsync(TUser user, TTenant tenant)
        {
            await CheckIsEnabled(tenant);

            await base.UpdateUserAsync(user, tenant);

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user.UserName);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    throw new AbpException("Unknown LDAP user: " + user.UserName);
                }

                UpdateUserFromPrincipal(user, userPrincipal);
            }
        }

        protected virtual bool ValidateCredentials(PrincipalContext principalContext, string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword)
        {
            return principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userNameOrEmailAddress, plainPassword, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
        }

        protected virtual void UpdateUserFromPrincipal(TUser user, UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
        {
            user.UserName = userPrincipal.SamAccountName;
            user.Name = userPrincipal.GivenName;
            user.Surname = userPrincipal.Surname;
            user.EmailAddress = userPrincipal.EmailAddress;

            if (userPrincipal.Enabled.HasValue)
            {
                user.IsActive = userPrincipal.Enabled.Value;
            }
        }

        protected virtual async Task<PrincipalContext> CreatePrincipalContext(TTenant tenant)
        {
            var tenantId = GetIdOrNull(tenant);

            return new PrincipalContext(
                await _settings.GetContextType(tenantId),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetDomain(tenantId)),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetContainer(tenantId)),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetUserName(tenantId)),
                ConvertToNullIfEmpty(await _settings.GetPassword(tenantId))
                );
        }

        private async Task CheckIsEnabled(TTenant tenant)
        {
            if (!_ldapModuleConfig.IsEnabled)
            {
                throw new AbpException("Ldap Authentication module is disabled globally!");
            }

            var tenantId = GetIdOrNull(tenant);
            if (!await _settings.GetIsEnabled(tenantId))
            {
                throw new AbpException("Ldap Authentication is disabled for given tenant (id:" + tenantId + ")! You can enable it by setting '" + LdapSettingNames.IsEnabled + "' to true");
            }
        }

        private static int? GetIdOrNull(TTenant tenant)
        {
            return tenant == null
                ? (int?)null
                : tenant.Id;
        }

        private static string ConvertToNullIfEmpty(string str)
        {
            return str.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
                ? null
                : str;
        }

    }
}
```

LdapSettings.cs

```
public class LdapSettings: ILdapSettings, ITransientDependency
    {

        protected ISettingManager SettingManager { get; }

        public LdapSettings(ISettingManager settingManager)
        {
            SettingManager = settingManager;
        }

        public virtual Task<bool> GetIsEnabled(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync<bool>(AppSettingNames.IsEnabled, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync<bool>(AppSettingNames.IsEnabled);
        }

        public virtual async Task<ContextType> GetContextType(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? (await SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.ContextType, tenantId.Value)).ToEnum<ContextType>()
                : (await SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.ContextType)).ToEnum<ContextType>();
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetContainer(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.Container, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.Container);
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetDomain(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.Domain, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.Domain);
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetUserName(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.UserName, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.UserName);
        }

        public virtual Task<string> GetPassword(int? tenantId)
        {
            return tenantId.HasValue
                ? SettingManager.GetSettingValueForTenantAsync(AppSettingNames.Password, tenantId.Value)
                : SettingManager.GetSettingValueForApplicationAsync(AppSettingNames.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

CoreModule.cs

```
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroLdapModule))]
    public class TestApp2020CoreModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {

            Configuration.Auditing.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;

            // Declare entity types
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Tenant = typeof(Tenant);
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Role = typeof(Role);
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.User = typeof(User);

            TestApp2020LocalizationConfigurer.Configure(Configuration.Localization);

            // Enable this line to create a multi-tenant application.
            Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = TestApp2020Consts.MultiTenancyEnabled;

            // IocManager.Register<ILdapSettings, MyLdapSettings>(); //change default setting source
            IocManager.Register<ILdapSettings, LdapSettings>();
            Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof(LdapSettings));
            // Configure roles
            AppRoleConfig.Configure(Configuration.Modules.Zero().RoleManagement);

            Configuration.Settings.Providers.Add<AppSettingProvider>();
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(TestApp2020CoreModule).GetAssembly());
        }

        public override void PostInitialize()
        {
            IocManager.Resolve<AppTimes>().StartupTime = Clock.Now;
            SettingManager settingsManager = IocManager.Resolve<SettingManager>();
            settingsManager.ChangeSettingForApplication(AppSettingNames.IsEnabled, "true");
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, all help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly with the constructor you used for `LdapAuthenticationSource`.  There's two problems

1. You declared the constructor `protected`.  That means the IoC framework isn't able to create a new `LdapAuthenticationSource`.
2. You didn't call the `base` constructor from your inherited class.  Instead, you stored the params in fields of the *derived class* so the base class cannot access them!

Try changing the constructor like this

```
public LdapAuthenticationSource(ILdapSettings settings, IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig ldapModuleConfig) : base(settings, ldapModuleConfig) { }
```

and removing these two lines

```
private readonly ILdapSettings _settings;
private readonly IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig _ldapModuleConfig;
```